# std::unique_ptr in lambda function causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

I have the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    int i = 5;
};


class B{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    std::function<void (void)> f;

    public:
    B(std::unique_ptr<A> a) 
        : a(std::move(a)), 
        f([&](){
                std::cout << a->i << '\n'; //segfaults when executing a->i
                })
    {}

    B()
        : a(new A),
        f([&](){
                std::cout << a->i << '\n'; //works fine 
                })
    {}

    void execLambda(){
        f();
    }

    void exec(){
       std::cout << a->i << '\n'; //works fine 
    }
};

int main(){

    B b1;
    b1.exec(); //works fine
    b1.execLambda(); //works fine

    B b2(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A));
    b2.exec(); //works fine
    b2.execLambda(); //will segfault
    return 0;

}
```

It seems when an object claims ownership of an existing unique_ptr and uses that unique_ptr in a lambda, a segmentation fault occurs.  Why does a segmentation fault occur in this specific case?  Is there anyway to use a unique_ptr in a lambda where ownership has been transferred?

Thank you very much!

Comment: At a guess I'd say the lambda is capturing the `a` from the constructor - the one you move from - not the one inside the class.

Comment: Don't give everything the same name? :-)

Comment: What Jonathan said, it's specified behaviour

Comment: @Jonathan: That was it! I cannot believe I did not realize this.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name members and method arguments the same thing. However, if you insist on doing so, you should be able to change your lambda capture to `[this]` instead of `[&]` to fix the problem.

As a commenter said:

> At a guess I'd say the lambda is capturing the a from the constructor
>   - the one you move from - not the one inside the class. – Jonathan Potter